# Add a dot after content:counter(mycounter)

Tags: html-lists

I'd like to add a dot after the content:counter(mycounter) in my Ol.

Current state without the dots:

[image: Current state without the dots]

How I'd like to present it:

[image: How I'd like to present it]

The thing is when the content:counter(mycounter) is applied the text removes the dots.

The css will explain the most part...

```css
/*Circle with number on the article-page*/

.article .article-info ol {
  list-style:none;
  counter-reset:mycounter;
  padding:0;
}

.article .article-info ol li {
  position:relative; 
  padding:5px 0;
}

.article .article-info ol li:before {
  content:counter(mycounter); 
  counter-increment:mycounter;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-30px;
  width:25px;
  line-height:20px;
  border-radius:50%;
  color:#B71A8B;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:7px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:1.2em
 margin-left:30px
}

.article .article-info ol li{
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
  opacity:.8;
}
```

So I'd like to somehow add something like this `content:counter(mycounter, ".")`.

I know about the list-style:none and that's the reason, but is there anyway possible to add the dot without removing the list-style:none;

Answer (score 0):

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: mycounter;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

ol li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

ol li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  content: counter(mycounter);
  counter-increment: mycounter;
}

ol li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ol>
```